# How to count rows and columns C Array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have function

```
- (void)sortColor:(int [3][3])colors
```

Are there any ways to count the rows and columns in Objective-C?
I know this is not an nsarray.I am wondering are there any simple way to count the row and col?

i got the col but row

col = sizeof(colors[0])/sizeof(*colors[0])

can anyone help?

Comment: This isn't an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you consider the first array count the row, eg: `int arr[# rows][# columns] = ...`

This is what you are looking for:

```
int rows = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
int columns = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(*arr[0]);
```

Not that this will simply return the size of which you created the C array at, not the number of actually existing values. If that is your goal, you do indeed need to use a different structure than what you have outlined above.

Comment: This is the correct answer to your question, but you may not be asking what you think you are... Read [Incomplete types](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Incomplete_types) on Wikipedia's page about `sizeof` - essentially if you are passed a pointer to a C array of unknown dimensions you *cannot* determine them.

Comment: This answer *only* works at the point of declaration of the array. If you pass the array into a function, this doesn't work anymore. The real answer is, "you already know the size, because you defined the size in the declaration." In this case the number of rows is 3 and number of columns is 3 because they were defined to be so.

Comment: hey friend.if I have a function in this way   newArr:(int[3][3])arr in OC..how to get the rows and columns?? it seems sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr) is not working.....@Daniel Amitay

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing like 2D array in objective-C or Swift. This is how you can simulate the behaviour though:

```
NSMutableArray *row1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSMutableArray *row2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", @"4", nil];
NSMutableArray *row3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"5", @"6", nil];

NSArray *multiArray = @[row1, row2, row3];

NSInteger rowCount = multiArray.count;
NSInteger columnCount = row1.count; // believing each row object have same number of objects
```

Answer (score -1):

You get the count of items in an NSArray by using the `count` method. Note that `int arr[3][3]` is *not* an NSArray, it's a standard C array. You generally can't get the count of standard C arrays, you have to keep track of it yourself.